# kernel NULL pointer dereference after wake_up_interruptible

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I'm trying to apply some examples of LDD3 book. but my module crash when i write to the device the caller process is killed, the crash is caused from wake_up_interruptible call.
I'm using kernel 5.3.0-42-generic.
the whole code: https://pastebin.com/aDiGDQTa
here is the code:

```
ssize_t device_write(struct file* fd, const char __user* buf, size_t size,
    loff_t* offset)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "MyLinuxModule: device is being written to, fd=%X.\n", fd);
    struct device_info mydevice = charDevices[MINOR(fd->f_inode->i_rdev)];
    if (*offset > DEVICE_BLOCK_SIZE) // reached Max size
    {
        return 0;
    }
    int true_len = min(size, DEVICE_BLOCK_SIZE - *offset);
    if (mutex_lock_interruptible(&mydevice.my_mutex))
        return -ERESTARTSYS;
    copy_from_user(mydevice.data, buf, true_len);
    mydevice.max_data_avaliable += true_len;
    mutex_unlock(&mydevice.my_mutex);
    printk(KERN_INFO "MyLinuxModule: my_queue=%X.\n", &mydevice.my_queue);
    wake_up_interruptible(&mydevice.my_queue);
    *offset += true_len;
    return true_len;
}
int setup_cdevice(int index)
{
    char* device_message = "Hello from the other side\n";
    // initiate the cdev struct
    cdev_init(&charDevices[index].chardev, &myfops);
    // initiate the data
    charDevices[index].data = kmalloc(DEVICE_BLOCK_SIZE, GFP_KERNEL);
    memcpy(charDevices[index].data, device_message, strlen(device_message));
    // initiate the semaphore & queue
    mutex_init(&charDevices[index].my_mutex);
    init_waitqueue_head(&charDevices[index].my_queue);
    charDevices[index].max_data_avaliable = 0;
    int err = cdev_add(&charDevices[index].chardev,
        MKDEV(MAJOR(majMin), MINOR(majMin) + index), numOfDevices);
    if (err) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "MyLinuxModule: cdev_add Error : %X\n", err);
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```
[ 8952.921117] BUG: kernel NULL pointer dereference, address: 0000000000000000
[ 8952.921119] #PF: supervisor instruction fetch in kernel mode
[ 8952.921120] #PF: error_code(0x0010) - not-present page
[ 8952.921121] PGD 0 P4D 0 
[ 8952.921123] Oops: 0010 [#7] SMP PTI
[ 8952.921137] CPU: 3 PID: 14892 Comm: main Tainted: G      D    OE     5.3.0-42-generic #34~18.04.1-Ubuntu
```

Comment: How did you fill `my_device.my_queue`? Each entry has a `func` member that is called by `__wake_up_common()`.  I will bet that is NULL.  I suggest you post the entire source of your driver, as the bug seems to be in code that you didn't show us.

Comment: I tried to add the whole code, but stackoveflow editor tells me that my post is mostly code and i need explain more. anyway i added the function the sets up the wait queue.

Comment: You could also post a link.

Comment: `setup_cdevice` looks okay because `init_waitqueue_head` initializes the `func` member to `default_wake_function`.  But don't you add entries to the queue elsewhere?  E.g. in your device read function, if no data is available, don't you add the reading task to the queue?  I would check that code.

Comment: the whole code
https://pastebin.com/aDiGDQTa

Comment: The line `struct device_info mydevice = ...` creates a **copy** of the device **struct**. But the waitqueues, like many other synchronization primitives, cannot be copied. You may, however, to store **pointer** to the device by changing the line to `struct device_info* mydevice = &charDevices[MINOR(fd->f_inode->i_rdev)];`.

Comment: Indeed, That solved the problem! Can you repost that as an answer to make it the best answer.<br> 
Can you explain why synchronization primitives cannot be copied ? if i that data structure is copied and identical to the original one but with a different pointer why does it crash ?